# Is Move a Turing-complete language?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, turing-complete, diem, move-lang

Will Move (on the Diem platform), like Ethereum, be turing complete? I have read the white paper but have been unable to decide.

This is the white paper: https://developers.libra.org/docs/assets/papers/libra-move-a-language-with-programmable-resources.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Turing-complete programming language. It supports while loops and Recursion.

See the [Move Basics documentation](https://developers.diem.com/main/docs/move-basics-loops) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Move is Turing complete which means that Libra is Turing complete.** Because of this, determining if a given Move program terminates cannot be decided statically. However, by ensuring that (1) every bytecode instruction has a non-zero cost, and (2) the amount of gas that any program can be started with is bounded, we get this termination property for programs almost free of cost.

Check out more details in the official blog: https://www.diem.com/en-us/blog/how-gas-works-on-libra-blockchain/

Answer (score -1):

It is either a turing complete or not a turing complete smart contract programming language.

Until now, there is no documentation mentioned this.